# How to Google map infoWindow always show

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I have my infoWindow always show?

```
map.addMarker({
        lat: 2.198436,
        lng: 102.244621,
        title: 'Company Name',
        infoWindow: {
            content: contentMarker
        },
        icon : 'css/colors/orange/images/icon-marker.png'
    });
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a little...take reference https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_events_infowindow

Comment: You probably should include which third party google maps library you are using (using a third party library may make it harder to do what you want...).

Comment: I don't think I'm using a 3rd party library to show my google map :(

Comment: `.addMarker` is not part of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Comment: I see. I see. I'll try to change to another code and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

the code for showing the infowindow after you click the marker: it shows the infowindow until you close.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ,
      map: map,
      title: ''
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

and if you want to see the infowindow by default:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: contentString,
   maxWidth: 200
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: uluru,
   map: map,
   title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

just added infowindow.open(map, marker); below.